# How add javascrip file to a node? (module)

Tags: 7, nodes, javascript

I have create a module who add a new node named SquareOffs. I make that in my squareoffs.info file. 
I would like to add to that node a javascript file, squareoffs.js, but I don't know to do that.

I have seen the drupal_add_js() documentation but I don't know understand how it works, how can I add the js file to this node??

Thank you very much for  your answers or your sugestions!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. `drupal_add_js()` is used to add js in your theme or custom module.

I assume that the node has been fetched under this custom module.

If you want to add in your module. Use this

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/js/squareoffs.js');
```

The js file can be added as inline and external too.

For more details [Click Here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)

Once the js file has been included, it will be applied to all the nodes under this custom module.

OR
If you want to add a js for particular content type. You can add preprocessor function in my custom module:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    if($vars['type'] == 'Nodetype') {
        drupal_add_js('drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/js/squareoffs.js');
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really use [`#attached`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached) rather than `drupal_add_js()` if you want the JS to be added every time the node's displayed (because this plays well with caching).

Comment: @Andy would you provide an example how to use `#attached` in `template_preprocess_node`? I've try to rewrite my preprocess function using #attached, and it won't load attached files after the node is cached, although it's working for the first page call.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. `template_preprocess_node()` is too late, because it's after you've already started rendering the render array. `hook_node_view()` or `hook_node_view_alter()` seem like sensible places to add any attached resources.

Comment: Thanks @Andy, I've also just figured out that and put them into `hook_node_view()`. It works great :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add your js through `drupal_add_js()` function. You can control on which pages this js should be added by implementing different hook and calling `drupal_add_js()` function in those hooks:

1) Use drupal_add_js() in hook_init() if you want to add this js on all drupal pages.

```
function mymoduel_init() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/js/mymodule.js');
}
```

2) Use drupal_add_js() in hook_node_view() with content type condition check if you want to add this js on only specific content types.

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if($node->type == 'my_content_type') {
    $node->content['#attached']['js'][] = array (
      'type' => 'file',
      'data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/js/mymodule.js',
    );
  }
}
```

3) Use drupal_add_js() in module's preprocess function if you want to add this js only on specific node

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->nid == 'your node nid') {
    // Add js
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/mymodule.awesome.js');
  }
}
```

You can implement this preprocess_page at theme level like mytheme_preprocess_page($variable) in theme's template.php file.

Comment: `hook_init()` is no longer the way for global JS - you can [use the info file instead](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722#adding-javascript). Also your third example I think should be done in the same way as your second.

Comment: @Andy you are right i just want to give the more possible ways.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your keen explanation! It work's perfectly, and I have better understand how drupal works!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on developing a website, I suggest you to use [JS injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector) Module and you can insert you jQuery/JavaScript into your website theme. To insert a jQuery, navigate to `Configuration -> development -> Js Injector -> Add.`

You can add your JScode as :

```
(function ($) { // your jquery goes here... })(jQuery);
```

If you are working on developing a module, go through this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/171213) and add your javaScript.